# git: how do I configure tracking a branch by merging and not by rebasing?

Tags: git, merge

I want to setup a local tracking branch that will be tracking a remote branch by merge and not by rebase.
When I do `git pull` I want to merge from the remote branch, not to rebase.

When I do:

```
git checkout -b someBranch origin/someBranch
```

and then

```
git remote show origin
```

I see:

```
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
  someBranch rebases onto remote someBranch
Local refs configured for 'git push':
  someBranch pushes to someBranch (local out of date)
```

The same thing also happens if I do

```
git checkout --track origin/someBranch
```

Is this somehow configured locally?
How do I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, GIT does `merge` during pulls. If yours is doing rebase, then it seems that at some point of time you had changed that behavior. Or someone helpful did that for you.

Citing after [this article (1)](https://coderwall.com/p/tnoiug/rebase-by-default-when-doing-git-pull) and [this article (2)](http://blog.aplikacja.info/2010/11/git-pull-rebase-by-default/) and [this article (3)](http://baddotrobot.com/blog/2013/07/09/automatically-rebase-on-git-pull/) - which all describe how to do the opposite thing:

(from 1)
There is a configuration flag in GIT that, when enabled, changed the default behavior of `pull` from `merge` to `rebase`. Check if you have it set:

```
# git >= 1.7.9:
git config --global pull.rebase
git config pull.rebase
```

In newer GIT clients, it works intuitively. It is enabled if it's `true`. Just turn the flag off.

In older however, it works differently.

```
# git < 1.7.9:
git config --global branch.autosetuprebase
git config branch.autosetuprebase

# and also
git config branch.<name>.rebase
```

When `autosetuprebase` is set to `always`, git automatically sets `rebase` flag on each new branch. This means that only you will probably want to not only disable `autosetuprebase`, but also to turn off the already-set `rebase` flag for each branch.

(from #2)
If you want another way (i.e. you've got old GIT client and tons of branches and you actually do mind writing a script that resets the flags) then another option is to create an alias for `git pull` that will add `--no-rebase` option, what will force it to do a merge.

(from #3)
This article says that the per-branch `rebase` flag is kept in a config file. So, after turning `autosetuprebase` off, it seems you can quickly disable rebaseing on all or some branches by remove all `rebase` lines from that config file.